# Where are my fonts coming from in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does rails come with custom fonts? If not, where are my fonts coming from?

I see this code in my css:

```
.hero-unit h1 {
            font-size: 54px;
            font-family: "museo-slab-1","museo-slab-2";
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            z-index: 30;
            position: relative;

    }
```

But I don't see that `font-face`declaration anywhere nor do I see any `app/assets/fonts` files. I see this:

and this in `main.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pictos';
    src: url('pictos-web.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('pictos-web.woff') format('woff'), url('pictos-web.ttf') format('truetype'), url('pictos-web.svg#webfontphKv1xv9') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and I see this in `app/images/new/home/<project>/d.css`:

[image]

In short, my font reckless is slow to load and loads after buttons load. This is problem. Why is this so slow? Why does my server on localhost seem to make a GET request to get the font? Is it on another process with a different port?? Also, how is my Future PT font being loaded? I can use it under font-family already. Where is this font being loaded?

Comment: The best way to know if this font is in your application is to check your browser developper console and check the streams. But the font should actually be in `assets/fonts` folder by convention.

Comment: Check the streams? Explain?

Comment: Well for example in Firefox, do a right-click "inspect" and go to Network tab. You can see all the assets. Click on "Type" column, this will sort assets by type. You can see all downloaded fonts by your app.

Comment: Why does it need a get request to get the font? Isn't this really slow?

Comment: It's not the get requests that makes it slow. I am not an HTTP expert but I think all assets are served the same way. My fonts load in milliseconds. Check your logs to be sure there is no problem. Also in Chrome, do a right-click inspect, then Audits, then Run Audits. Lighthouse will make an audit. After audit, in Performance section, you can see how long it takes to load assets. (click on View trace to see the full stack of asset loading)